# Distributivity of two operations over the other implies endless calculation

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I am studying Denlinger's "Elements of Real Analysis". There is a section of logic in the appendix.
Simple propositions are connected by logical connectives to form compound propositions.
$\land$(and) and $\lor$(or) are two of the logical connectives.
We can easily prove that
$\land$ is distributed over $\lor$ and
$\lor$ is distributed over $\land$.

Suppose $A,B$ and $C$ are the propositions.
$A\land(B\lor C)=(A\land B)\lor (A\land C)$
$\implies A\land(B\lor C)=((A\land B)\lor A)\land ((A\land B)\lor C)$
$\implies A\land(B\lor C)=((A\lor A)\land (B\lor A))\land ((A\lor C)\land (B\lor C))$
$\implies A\land(B\lor C)=\Big(A\land(B\lor A)\Big)\land \Big((A\lor C)\land (B\lor C)\Big)$
$\implies A\land(B\lor C)=\Big((A\land(B\lor A))\land(A\lor C)\Big)\land \Big((A\land(B\lor A))\land(B\lor C)\Big)$
So, in this way our steps of calculation keep on going.

We know that in the field axioms, "$.$ is distributed over $+$" but "$+$ is not distributed over $.$"
But if "$+$ is also distributed over $.$".
Then in case of real numbers,
Ex- $4\times(5+3)=20+(4\times 3)$
As $+$ is distributed over $\times$
$\implies 4\times(5+3)=(20+4)\times(20+3)$
$\implies 4\times(5+3)=24\times(20+3)$
$\implies 4\times(5+3)=(24\times 20)+(24\times 3)$
$\implies 4\times(5+3)=44+(24\times 3)$
$\implies 4\times(5+3)=(44+24)\times(44+3)$
In this way we can see that the calculation has no end.

I have the following questions,
**i)** Is it justified to have two logical connectives and both are distributed over the other. Though we can prove using truth tables that $\land$ and $\lor$ are distributed over the other. But I think atmost one of them can be distributed over the other. If both are distributed over each other, then it lead to endless calculation as we have seen above for the ($\land$ and $\lor$) connectives and also in ($+$ and $\times$) in $\mathbb R$?

**ii)** So can we say in general that for any set if we define two operations satisfying closure property and commutativity then both of them can't be distributed over the other?

Please clarify the doubt!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having two (distinct) operations distribute over one another. Just because one expression is equal to an infinite number of other expressions with unbounded lengths doesn't imply anything in the direction you mean. Is $0 = 0+0 = 0+0+0 = 0+0+0+0 = 0+0+0+0+0 = \cdots$ problematic?

Comment: Have you stopped to consider what you yourself have said here? You say "Though we can prove using truth tables that ∧ and ∨ are distributed over the other'. But then you follow it with "But I think atmost one of them can be distributed over the other." You just *admitted* you can prove that they do distribute over each other, but then you say, you think they don't. What part of that proof are you disputing? You should be looking for flaws in your argument that they can't.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair , I understood the proof. But I have a doubt that doesn't distributivity of two operations on the other leads to endless calculations. How to fix it?

Comment: @Hayden , the example you have taken is for the additive identity. Isn't for any other number not equal to 0, the endless calculation is a trouble? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: How to fix what? There is nothing broken here. If you want to keep repeating a process to see where it takes you, go ahead. If it isn't taking you anywhere you want to go, *stop doing it* and do something else instead. Only a tiny fraction of mathematical operations are reductive - breaking something down into pieces that eventually reduce no further. Distributivity is not amongst them, nor is there any need for it to be.

Comment: @Iti The point is exactly what Paul Sinclair points out -- nothing is ever forcing your hand to use distributivity (or perform any particular singular action to an expression in an attempt to 'simplify' it) in order to evaluate something like $A \wedge (B \vee C)$. Disbtributivity says that for any $A,B,C$, we have $A \wedge (B \vee C) = (A \wedge B) \vee (A \wedge C)$. The 'for any $A,B,C$' is telling us that this isn't holding in some higher abstraction, it's holding for actual propositions (and really just their truth values), so once you know those truth values just calculate the result.